# CreateUserWizard Username and Email Enumeration

Tags: asp.net, security

I've been doing a security review of our website and found an issue with CreateUserWizard.
We do not let people sign up with a duplicate email address or username. The CreateUserWizard will verify this for me but the problem is that I can write a script to hit our server and try username and pretty quickly get a list of username by enumerating through them.

I want to add recaptcha but I can't seem to get it to verify this before it verifies the username.  Is there a way to do this?

```
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/PleaseVerify.aspx" CssClass="CreateUserWizard" StepNextButtonStyle-CssClass="NextButton" StartNextButtonStyle-CssClass="NextButton" FinishCompleteButtonStyle-CssClass="FinishButton" CreateUserButtonText="Create my ID"
        CompleteSuccessText="Your account has been created, but before you can login you must first verify your email address. A message has been sent to the email address you specified. Please check your email inbox and follow the instructions in that email to verify your account."
        DisableCreatedUser="True" OnSendingMail="CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail" DuplicateUserNameErrorMessage="That username is already in use, if you think this is you can LINK REMOVED Otherwise try a different username."
        DuplicateEmailErrorMessage="That email is already in use, try to <a href='/ForgotPassword.aspx'>recover your password</a>." InvalidPasswordErrorMessage="Please supply at least five letters in your password.">
```

Comment: You might want to give us a little more information about how you are doing captcha etc. than just your CUW control's configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the username is validated on the client side, so you could override your  CreateUserWizard's CreateUserError event handler, check your captcha and NOT pass back an error about the username being already in use. I use a custom control captcha that I pieced together from www.codinghorror.com (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/captcha-control-coda.html), and it triggers before the backend code attempts to create the user and determines that the username/email is in use.

Comment: I ended up just not using the Create user Wizard so I haven't tested this answer but it sounds correct. I posted my solution also.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the create user wizard and just doing the simple login in the button handler.

```
    recaptcha.Validate();
    if (!recaptcha.IsValid)
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Code.";
        return;
    }
    if (!IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }
    var duplicateEmail = Membership.FindUsersByEmail(Email.Text);
    if (duplicateEmail.Count > 0)
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = "That email is already in use, try to <a href='/ForgotPassword.aspx'>recover your password</a>.";
        return;   
    }
    var duplicateUsername = Membership.FindUsersByName(UserName.Text);
    if (duplicateUsername.Count > 0)
    {
         ErrorMessage.Text = "That username is already in use, if you think this is you can <a href='http://www.nanaimo.ca/dashboard/'>login</a>, otherwise try a different username.";
         return;   
    }
    var newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text);
    newUser.IsApproved = false;
    Membership.UpdateUser(newUser);
```